# NSScanner behavior

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsscanner

I am very new to iOS development.  I am trying to parse a simple csv file that has about 10 lines separated by commas. I am using the code below but not able understand why `NSScanner`, when parsing the fields (fields in the code below) does not go to the next string after the comma. I have to execute the line

```
[fields scanCharactersFromSet:fieldCharSet intoString:nil];
```

to make it go past the delimiter. However, I don't have to do the same thing for lines - `NSScanner` automatically sets the position to the next line past the newline. In both cases I am using the same method - [lines scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString] Is there something I am not understanding?

Here is the test file I am trying to parse:

```
Name,Location,Number,Units
A,AA,4,mm
B,BB,3.5,km
C,CC,10.2,mi
D,DD,2,mm
E,EE,6,in
F,FF,2.8,m
G,GG,3.7,km
H,HH,4.3,mm
I,II,4,km
```

Here is my code:

```
-(void)parseFile {
    NSCharacterSet *lineCharSet = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];
    NSCharacterSet *fieldCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:self.separator];
    // import the file

    NSStringEncoding *encoding = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.absoluteURL usedEncoding:encoding error:&error];
    NSString *line,*field;


    NSScanner *lines = [NSScanner scannerWithString:data]; 
    while (![lines isAtEnd]) {

        [lines scanUpToCharactersFromSet:lineCharSet intoString:&line];//automatically sets to next line - why?



        NSLog(@"%@\n",line);

        NSScanner *fields = [NSScanner scannerWithString:line];

        while (![fields isAtEnd]) {

            [fields scanUpToCharactersFromSet:fieldCharSet intoString:&field];

            [fields scanCharactersFromSet:fieldCharSet intoString:nil]; //have to do this otherwise will not go to next symbol

            NSLog(@"%@\n", field);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way `NSScanner` works.  When you use `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:`, it scans characters up to *but not including* the characters in the set.  If you want it to move past characters in the set, you have two options:

1. Make it scan those characters.  You are doing this now using `scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:`.  Another way you could do it is `[fields scanString:self.separator intoString:nil]`.
2. Tell the scanner that the separator character is to be skipped, using `setCharactersToBeSkipped:`.  However, this will make it hard for you to detect empty fields.

The scanner's default set of characters-to-be-skipped includes the newline.  That's why your outer scanner skips the newline.

You could do this entirely using `componentsSeparatedByString:`, instead of using `NSScanner`.  Example:

```
-(void)parseFile {
    NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.absoluteURL usedEncoding:encoding error:&error];

    for (NSString *line in [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
        if (line.length == 0)
            continue;

        NSLog(@"line: %@", line);

        for (NSString *field in [line componentsSeparatedByString:self.separator]) {
            NSLog(@"    field: %@", field);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rob,Thanks for your answer. But, why does it automatically increment the scan position to the next line when I use this on the lines.

Comment: Rob, Thanks for your reply. The default behavior for NSScanner is to skip newline and whitespace. I missed this part. - rp

Comment: @RXP you should check this answer as correct to reward the help rob has given to you

Comment: This is the best approach if you want to count lines. However, "\n" may or may not give the result you expect, read Apple's [String Programming Guide: Line and Paragraph Separator Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsParagraphBreaks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005016-SW2)